# Flask & Python: Remember form data after POST

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to let the user create a "meeting" with several settings on a website.

1. User fills out a form
2. Form is send via POST
3. Website shows a summary page with the data entered by the user
4. User can go back and edit that data or press the "okay" button
5. Data from user is added to the database

I'm stuck at step 4. 
`session_create.html` contains the form. I can submit the form and the data gets validated (wtforms). If the form data is validated, I display it on the `session_summary.html` page. The data is displayed there correctly.

The routes file:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def create():

  form = CreateSessionForm()

  if form.validate_on_submit():

    data = {}
    data["title"] = form.title.data
    data["description"] = form.description.data

    data["date"] = form.date.data
    data["time"] = form.time.data
    data["sessiontype"] = form.sessiontype.data 
    data["host"] = current_user.username

    if form.duration.data:
        data["duration"] = form.duration.data 
    else:
        data["duration"] = 0

    return render_template('session_summary.html', title='Create a session', data=data)

  return render_template('session_create.html', title='Create a session', form=form)
```

But my problem is that from here on I don't know how to access the data if the user confirms that the data entered was correct. Do I need to send all data in a hidden form to `session_summary.html`?

I'm sorry for not being more precise. I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: HTTP being a stateless protocol, the simple canonical solution is indeed to resend all the required data via a form so the user submit them again. This doesn't have to be a hidden form though - the user may want to correct a mistake after proof-reading. To distinguish wether it's a "preview" submission or a final validation, the trick is to add an hidden field in the form whose value depends on the current step.